# EPPlus: Set Bar Direction on DataBar ConditionalFormatting

Tags: epplus

Is there a way to set the bar direction programmatically for a DataBar conditional formatting rule that is added to a range using ConditionalFormatting.AddDataBar()?

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to do this and alter the "Axis settings" to "Cell midpoint". I'd also like to alter the Negative colour options.